# How to include php inside an .html file without htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, yahoo

I am updating my website to show recent blog post. I originally changed my homepage to index.php but then my yahoo shopping cart script wont work. I did some research and the only answers I have found is to put these two lines in my .htaccess file: 
AddType application/x-httpd-php htm html php 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

But yahoo small business wont let you use htacess. Any suggestions???

Comment: Your shopping cart script should work unless some part of it is referenced to index.html, but idk I might be wrong.

Comment: When you make AddHandler, your .html will act like php. It wouldn't be a solution. We have to find what breaks your cart script.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to stick with index.html, use an iframe to include the blog post inside index.hml.

What error are you experiencing with your yahoo shopping cart script?

I'm pretty sure you can fix it by replacing any references to index.html with index.php or even better http://your-webpage-domain.com/your_directory/

Also make sure if you're going with the php script, that you've removed the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can you build another php page and include it with iframe?

Comment: That would be a tedious solution! Well, at least for me, I hate iFrames :P

Answer (score 0):

Rename your index.html to index.php again and make the form like that

```
<?php
echo '

<form method="post" action="http://order.store.yahoo.net/cgi-bin/wg-order?yhst-12345678901234+10001">
Description: Mercedes<br>
Price: 1,000<br>
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>

';
?>
```